# How to add rel attribute when img src not empty?

Tags: jquery, addition, attr, prettyphoto, rel

```
<div class="otherProducts">
  <a href="http://metroplastasansor.bilginet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hidrolik-tampon-metroplast-asansor-41943-390057037-b.jpg" class="otherLink"><img src="http://metroplastasansor.bilginet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hidrolik-tampon-metroplast-asansor-41943-390057037-b.jpg" class="productThumb"></a>
  <a href="" class="otherLink"><img src="" class="productThumb"></a>
  <a href=""><img src="" class="productThumb"></a></div>
```

How can I add rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" to a with jquery? Only links with not empty src!

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. What does "Only links with not empty src!" mean?

Comment: I think you'll find that the 'rel' needs to be applied to the parent `<a>` element, not the `<img>` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`.

I've selected all images withing `.otherProducts`. I then pass a function to filter than will return true if the `src` attribute is truthy and false if it has a falsy (blank) value.

Then use `.attr()` to change the `rel` attribute for the closest `<a>`s to the remaining selections:

```
$('.otherProducts img').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).closest('a').attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[gallery]');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLm2jp2h/2/)

Comment: Thanks George! My Problem has been fixed. I can use this code likely. j('.otherProducts img').filter(function(){
    return j(this).attr('src');
}).parent().attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[gallery]');

Comment: Yes, `src` property is an absolute path, how about `this.getAttribute(...)`?

Comment: @Vohuman I know. Why `.getAttribute()` over `.attr()`? It's really a matter of personal preference, unless you are worries about (minor) speed differences.

Comment: @George `.getAttribute()` is not shorter than `.attr()`, that's for sure. Let's just say that was my mistake about img src absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).has('img[src!=""]');
})
.attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[gallery]');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzbh1u8f/1)

Answer (score 0):

I can used this code:

```
$('.otherProducts img').filter(function(){
return $(this).attr('src');}).parent().attr('rel', 'prettyPhoto[gallery]');
```

Thanks George!

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, you can mention to @George about adding `.parent()` and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.each` and `.parent()` like:

```js
 $('.productThumb').each(function() {
   if ($(this).attr("src") != "") {
     //if it has source
     $(this).parent().attr("rel", "prettyPhoto[gallery]");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="otherProducts">
  <a href="http://metroplastasansor.bilginet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hidrolik-tampon-metroplast-asansor-41943-390057037s-b.jpg" class="otherLink">

    <img src="http://metroplastasansor.bilginet.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hidrolik-tampon-metroplast-asansor-41943-390057037-b.jpg" class="productThumb">

  </a>
  <a href="" class="otherLink">
    <img src="" class="productThumb">
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" class="productThumb">
  </a>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5gnettxg/

Answer (score -1):

try this piece of code

```
if($("img.productThumb").attr("src")!=""){

  $(this).attr("rel","prettyPhoto[gallery]");

}
```

Comment: Well, if you use this code in `<script></script>`, `this` points to `window`.